# Priority between normal function and Template function

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

In the following code, the main function uses normal function instead of Template function.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
void num(T t){cout<<"T : "<<t;}

void num(int a){cout<<"wT : "<<a;}


int main()
{
    num(5);
    return 0;
}
```

What is the possible reason behind this?

Comment: function best matching argument is chosen first.

Comment: @Anycorn: in c++, is  it default to choose first normal function?

Comment: Let me clarify - if a normal function matches the *type*, it will be chosen.  for example if it was `num(char a)`, temlate would be chosen.

Comment: I asked a similar question ago:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431735/c-standard-overloaded-function-resolution-matching

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is the compiler choosing this template function over an overloaded non-template function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594326/why-is-the-compiler-choosing-this-template-function-over-an-overloaded-non-templ)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To call the template method in this case, you need to invoke the method explicitly with `num<int>(5)` instead of `num(5)`. Although the compiler can infer, non-generic method is preferred to a generic one. You can take a look at this behavior here http://ideone.com/ccDJP.

Comment: thanks. I want to hear this statement"Although the compiler can infer, it'll prefer a non-generic method to a generic one".

Comment: Yes, if you think about it, using a non-generic causes a new template method to be created in the text (C++ template essentially duplicate the method for every different type that is used). Why go through that effort if there's already one :)

Comment: Alternative way to invoke the template variant `num<>(5);`.

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at Herb Sutter's excellent article ["Why not specialize function templates?"](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm)

To quote:

"Finally, let's focus on function templates only and consider the overloading rules to see which ones get called in different situations. The rules are pretty simple, at least at a high level, and can be expressed as a classic two-class system:

1. **Nontemplate functions are first-class citizens**. A plain old nontemplate function that matches the parameter types as well as any function template will be selected over an otherwise-just-as-good function template.
2. If there are no first-class citizens to choose from that are at least as good, then **function base templates as the second-class citizens** get consulted next. Which function base template gets selected depends on which matches best and is the "most specialized" (important note: this use of "specialized" oddly enough has nothing to do with template specializations; it's just an unfortunate colloquialism) according to a set of fairly arcane rules:

   - If it's clear that there's one "most specialized" function base template, that one gets used. If that base template happens to be specialized for the types being used, the specialization will get used, otherwise the base template instantiated with the correct types will be used.
   - Else if there's a tie for the "most specialized" function base template, the call is ambiguous because the compiler can't decide which is a better match. The programmer will have to do something to qualify the call and say which one is wanted.
   - Else if there's no function base template that can be made to match, the call is bad and the programmer will have to fix the code."

In your code example, as pointed out by David Z., the non-template function `void num(int a)` will be selected because it is matched in the first rule. Any additional **function templates will only be considered if they would be a better match**.