# Overloading priority between different function templates with identical name

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

Sorry for the unclear title, feel free to edit it if you find a better one. A related topic has been deeply discussed in [Priority between normal function and Template function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291405/priority-between-normal-function-and-template-function),
  but I did not find the answer to my question.

My code is:

```
template<typename T>
void f(T t){std::cout << "Template 1" << std::endl;} // template 1

template<typename T, typename B>
void f(T t){std::cout << "Template 2" << std::endl;} // template 2

int main () {
   f(1);  // line 1, template 1 will be called
   f<int>(1);  // template 1 will be called
   f<int,int>(1);  // template 2 will be called
}
```

What is the possible reason that  the template 1 function is called at line 1? Is it well defined in the specification?

At line 1, I think the compiler should give an "ambiguous overload" error.

Answer (score 5):

`B` cannot be deduced (no parameter has type `B`) so template 1 is the only possible overload left.