# Why isn't it necessary to specialize for `std::nullptr_t` if there's a specialized function AND a templated function

Tags: c++, null, language-lawyer, overload-resolution, nullptr

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void fun(const char* s){
    if (s == nullptr) {
        puts("const char* nullptr");
    } else {
        printf("%s\n", s);
    }
}

template <typename T>
void fun(T* p){
    printf("%p\n", p);
}

int main() {
    int a;
    fun("abc"); // Resolves to fun(const char*)
    fun(&a); // Specializes the template to int*
    fun(nullptr); // Uses fun(const char*)??
    fun(NULL); // Same as above
}
```

I'm surprised that `g++ 7.2.0` does **not** throw an error about ambiguous overload resolution, as I think `nullptr` and `NULL` could fit into *any* pointer type, including `fun(int*)` specialized from the template, provided there isn't an overload specialized for `std::nullptr_t`.

Why does `fun(nullptr)` and `fun(NULL)`resolves directly to `fun(const char *)`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for formatting help.

Comment: This one is related, maybe a bit too far away from your question to be a dupe though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291405/priority-between-normal-function-and-template-function

Comment: Please add a return statement inside the if statement, otherwise the behavior is undefined when `s == nullptr`

Comment: @krzaq Added. Thanks.

Comment: Because `T` can't be deduced; what should it be?

Comment: @songyuanyao So why isn't it an ambiguous resolution?

Comment: @iBug `T` can't be deduced, means the template overload won't be considered in overload resolution; it's eliminated before that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::nullptr_t` is not a pointer, so it will not pattern-match `T*` in your function template.

As counter-intuitive as this is, the following assert will not fire:

```
static_assert(std::is_pointer<std::nullptr_t>() == false);
```

As for [`NULL`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL), it is an implementation-defined macro. If cppreference is to be believed, it's either an integer literal with value of zero (so not a pointer), or a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`, which is explained above. It is *not* a `void*` pointer.